# osticket fetch phone number via mysql query

Tags: osticket

I am using OSTICKET 1.9.12 on Ubuntu 12.

Is there any way I can get registered user 'phone number' via mysql query?

I tried to search on there forums and internet, but didn't got any working method.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully your problem would have been solved by now, but if not, you can try this query:

```
SELECT T3.value FROM %table_prefix%_user T1
    JOIN %table_prefix%_form_entry T2 on T1.id = T2.object_id
    Join %table_prefix%_form_entry_values T3 on T2.id = T3.entry_id
    where T1.id=5 and T3.field_id=3;
```

In order for this to work, replace %table_prefix% with the table prefix in your OSTicket database. Also replace '5' in where clause (T1.id=5) to the user's id.